# Why I'm Facing the error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

This is a Laravel & Vue Js Project.
Everything works fine but why I'm facing [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" type error.

My Vue File

```
<template>
<p>Sold By: {{product.user.name}}</p>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                product:{},
            }
        },

        methods: {
            loadData(){
                axios.get('/api/'+this.$route.params.slug+'/product')
                .then(response => {
                    this.product = response.data;
                },
                ()=> {});
            }
        },

        created(){
            this.$Progress.start();
            this.loadData();
            this.$Progress.finish();
        },
    }
</script>
```

My Controller

```
public function getProduct($slug)
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug',$slug)->with('brand','category','subCategory','productImages','featureDescriptions','colors','variants','user')->first();
        return response()->json($product, 200);
    }
``

Now I want to show my User name in Vue file <p>Sold By: {{product.user.name}}</p>. It showing User Name With an error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". when I show the user data <p>Sold By: {{product.user}}</p>, It show user all data without error. Now how i show user name without error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `<p>` is being rendered while product is still an empty object (`product: {}`).

You could use `v-if` to render only if product already has been loaded.

```js
<template>
  <p v-if="dataLoaded">Sold By: {{ product.user.name }}</p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      product: {},
      dataLoaded: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    loadData() {
      axios.get("/api/" + this.$route.params.slug + "/product").then(
        (response) => {
          this.product = response.data;
          this.dataLoaded = true;
        },
        () => {}
      );
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.$Progress.start();
    this.loadData();
    this.$Progress.finish();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't add an arbitrary `data` property to circumvent the display of an error. It's a common anti-pattern. I've added a note to my answer explaining why that is.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory: you're using `{{product.user.name}}` in the template. But before the `product` has returned from BE, `product.user` is `undefined` and therefore does not have a `.name` property.

The simplest fix would be to place a `v-if` on the `<p>`:

```
<p v-if="product.user">Sold By: {{product.user.name}}</p>
```

---

Another generic solution for this type of problem is to use a computed:

```
<template>
  <p>Sold By: {{productUserName}}</p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    productUserName() {
      return this.product.user?.name || '';
    }
  }
  // ...
}
</script>
```

You can read more about optional chaining operator (used above) (`?.`) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).
Because it's a fairly new addition to JavaScript, Vue doesn't currently support it in `<template>` tags (but it works in `<script>`).

---

*Additional note:* a common mistake is to add an additional `data` member instead of using the source of the error (`product.user` in this case) either directly or through a `computed`. This creates two problems:

- it decouples `product.user` from rendering the `<p>`. Which means that if BE returns a `product` without a `user`, you'll still get the error, because you've set `dataLoaded` to `true` but the template still tries to read the property `.name` of `user`, which is falsy and therefore does not have a `.name`.
- you create unnecessary boilerplate: anyone trying to understand or modify your code at a later time has to figure out the arbitrary connection between `dataLoaded` and `product.user`.

One of the reasons Vue is loved for is because it doesn't require boilerplate code, unlike other frameworks (i.e: Angular). Keep it that way! By using `v-if="product.user"` in the template, someone reading that code will immediately understand the rendering logic, without having to look at the component code. Decreasing the time needed to figure out the code on a regular basis will greatly decrease the time needed to modify it, should you (or someone else) ever need to. This results into more flexible, more scalable code. Less bugs, less time spent => more money.